# showing text on label or textview taking more time while on console it is displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, nsstring, uilabel

I have encountered with such problem first time and needs your help.

I am fetching twitter user info and with NSLog i can see it in console but when i am displaying it on label or text view it is taking more time, almost of 1 minute.

The code i am using is ....

```
_accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
            ACAccountType *accountType = [_accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

 [_accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                                completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)

             // Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.

             {
                 // Did user allow us access?
                 if (granted == YES)
                 {
                     // Populate array with all available Twitter accounts
                     NSArray *arrayOfAccounts = [_accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                     [arrayOfAccounts retain];

                     // Populate the tableview
                     if ([arrayOfAccounts count] > 0)
                         NSLog(@"print %@",[arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0]);
                     //
                     ACAccount *twitterAccount = [arrayOfAccounts objectAtIndex:0];

                     NSString *userID = [[twitterAccount valueForKey:@"properties"] valueForKey:@"user_id"];
                     NSLog(@"print user id is %@",userID);// Here i can see immediately 

                    testLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi ,%@",userID];// Here it is taking more time...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You are updating your UI element from a asynchronous thread**. That's why the issue happens.

Replace:

```
testLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi ,%@",userID];
```

With:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

   testLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi ,%@",userID];

});
```

Remember: You should update your UI elements from main thread only.

In your case you wrote the code inside a `block`, blocks will execute in a asynchronous thread not in main thread. You are updating your UI element from there. That will cause the issue, so you need to update the UI from main thread, for that you are using the `dispatch_get_main_queue`.

Comment: Thanks Midhun ..  it solved that problem but could you please describe it in detail.

Comment: @Sawant: With pleasure :) Please remember **Update UI elements from Main thread Only**

Comment: @Sawant: added more details

Comment: Thanks Midhun , i will remember this ever.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure the completion block is running on main thread.

try below code..

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  testLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Hi ,%@",userID];
});
```